# Static Files and Heroku

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, heroku

I've been gathering some ideas for a web app, which is to include functionality for merging PDFs based upon user selections. There isn't going to be a giant amount of documents, but the problem is that the Node plugin I'm using to merge them doesn't seem to be able to draw them down from S3 for the process. I know that storing static files on Heroku is frowned-upon, but if they're not something that the user changes, then is it okay to store some of them there, or is there something I'm overlooking? The argument I've heard against storing anything on Heroku is that it's ephemeral, so the PDFs that the user generates would be deleted when the Dyno is restarted...but that's no problem, because when they create them, it's just a one and done download situation. Am I going to run into any issues storing just 100-200 MB of PDFs on the Dyno, or is there some clever way I could bridge that gap?

Comment: Heroku best practice , IMO , would not extend beyond utilizing /tmp in the fs for the duration of a 'unit of work'. If you want to make your app an exception to that rule go ahead but its not really production ready. with some search in npm , you may find OSS adaptors  - like and API for S3  making it easy to add persistence and prod ready fs to your app.  https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-s3-adapter

Comment: Thanks so much...I'll check it out, and I appreciate your help!